# sql-connect: (setting-constant nil)

Tags: sql-interactive-mode, sql, sql-mode

I am using latest Helm from MELPA on Emacs `GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.16.6) of 2015-09-11`

When I issue `sql-connect` I see this:

[image: 2015-09-11-115647_672x177_scrot]

The only connection I have saved (in custom.el) is the second one, `boccaperta`. First time I select `boccaperta` from that list this is the error I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (setting-constant nil)
  (let ((nil (quote nil))) (sql-product-interactive (quote postgres) (quote nil)))
  eval((let ((nil (quote nil))) (sql-product-interactive (quote postgres) (quote nil))))
  sql-connect("boccaperta" nil)
  funcall-interactively(sql-connect "boccaperta" nil)
  call-interactively(sql-connect nil nil)
  command-execute(sql-connect)
```

It only happens the first time I select `boccaperta`. If I try again, I can connect to my DB.

It also happens with Helm disabled, by the way. And it happens with `emacs -Q` as well.

Comment: Frankly, this looks like a bug in `sql-get-product-feature`. The way it is used, it should not return `nil` under any circumstances, but it does this intentionally. If you have time for it, filing a bug report would seem like a way to go about it. The problematic line is this: `(setq param-var (sql-get-product-feature sql-product :sqli-login nil t))`, which, if `param-var` is set to `nil`, will then result in the error you see.

Comment: Apparently it is an already reported bug: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-12/msg00980.html